# Jenkins-GitLab Integration: How to Clone Source Branch of Merge Request in Jenkins?"

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks, branching-strategy, merge-request

I've successfully set up a Jenkins-GitLab webhook connection to trigger Jenkins builds when a Merge Request (MR) is created in the GitLab repository, specifically when the MR status is marked as 'open'. Now, from the Jenkins side, I'm aiming to clone the source branch associated with the MR in order to access its codebase. How can I accomplish this in my Jenkins pipeline or job configuration?

The objective is to dynamically retrieve and clone the source branch referenced in the Merge Request within the Jenkins build process. What steps or configurations within Jenkins would facilitate this source branch checkout based on the MR triggered from GitLab?

Guidance or insights into achieving this integration between Jenkins and GitLab for retrieving the MR's source branch would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!